# Why makes wxURL in wxThread a SIGSEGV?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to download a zip file and extract it. And I use a free function for that.

```
auto downloadAndExtractFile(const wxString& url) -> bool {
    // download file
    auto temp_file = wxFileName::CreateTempFileName("download_", (wxFile*)nullptr);
    auto dl = wxURL(url);
    
    auto err = dl.GetError();
    if (err == wxURL_NOERR) {
        wxInputStream *in = dl.GetInputStream();//TODO: SIGSEGV if func called from second thread
        if (in && in->IsOk()) {
            auto out = wxFFileOutputStream(temp_file);
            in->Read(out);
        } else {
            //TODO: log
            return false;
        }
        delete in;
    } else {
        //TODO: log
        return false;
    }
    
    // extract file
    wxExtractZipFiles(temp_file, wxFileName(temp_file).GetPath());
    //TODO: check?

    // delete downloaded file
    wxRemoveFile(temp_file);
    //TODO: check?

    return true;
}
```

But I want to use wxThread to do that. In this case I get a SIGSEGV when I use the following class.

```
class BackgoundThread: public wxThread {
private:    // helpers
protected:  // helpers
public:     // helpers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:    // member fields
    wxFrame     *m_parent_{nullptr};
    wxString    m_selected_filename_;
protected:  // member fields
public:     // member fields
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:    // member inline getter/setter/toggle
protected:  // member inline getter/setter/toggle
public:     // member inline getter/setter/toggle
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:    // member methods
protected:  // member methods
public:     // member methods
    auto Entry() -> ExitCode override {
        // disable start button
        wxCommandEvent event_disable_start_button(wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, BUTTON_START_DISABLE_ID);
        m_parent_->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event_disable_start_button);
        
        auto time_in_seconds = [](long time_in_ms) -> float {
            return ((float)time_in_ms)/1000;
        };
        
        auto all_timer = wxStopWatch();
        
        // start download
        auto url_str = wxString("http://www.mattmahoney.net/dc/" + m_selected_filename_ + ".zip");
        wxCommandEvent event_download_started(wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, TEXT_CTRL_APPEND_TEXT_ID);
        event_download_started.SetString(wxString::Format("[.2f] Downloading/Extracting file: %s\n", time_in_seconds(all_timer.Time()), url_str));
        m_parent_->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event_download_started);
        
        auto tempDir = wxFileName::GetTempDir();
        auto filePath = tempDir + wxFileName::GetPathSeparator() + m_selected_filename_;
        
        auto timer_download = wxStopWatch();
        downloadAndExtractFile(url_str);
        timer_download.Pause();
        wxCommandEvent event_download_ended(wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, TEXT_CTRL_APPEND_TEXT_ID);
        event_download_ended.SetString(wxString::Format("[.2f] download/extract done (%ld ms)\n", time_in_seconds(all_timer.Time()), timer_download.Time()));
        
        // enable start button
        wxCommandEvent event_enable_start_button(wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, BUTTON_START_ENABLE_ID);
        m_parent_->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event_enable_start_button);
        
        return 0;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:    // constructors/destructor
protected:  // constructors/destructor
public:     // constructors/destructor
    BackgoundThread(wxFrame *parent, wxString selected_filename = "enwik8", wxThreadKind kind = wxTHREAD_DETACHED): wxThread(kind), m_parent_(parent), m_selected_filename_(selected_filename) {}
};
```

If I use the code from entry() in a wxFrame (main thread) then there is no SIGSEGV. So what's wrong with the thread class?

PS: I also tried:

```
wxHTTP request;
request.Connect(url);
auto err = request.GetError();
if (err == wxPROTO_NOERR) {
    wxInputStream *in = request.GetInputStream(temp_file); //TODO: SIGSEGV if func called from second thread
    ...
```

and:

```
wxFileSystem fs;
fs.AddHandler(new wxInternetFSHandler());
wxFSFile *file = fs.OpenFile(url); //TODO: SIGSEGV if func called from second thread
...
```

PS2: the backtrace:

```
wxSocketFDBasedManager::Install_Callback(wxSocketImpl*, wxSocketNotify) 0x00000000004e006d
wxSocketImplUnix::DoEnableEvents(int, bool) 0x00000000004e01c3
wxSocketBase::SetFlags(int) 0x00000000004ddca9
wxSocketBase::Peek(void*, unsigned int) 0x00000000004de6ab
wxProtocol::ReadLine(wxSocketBase*, wxString&) 0x00000000004d8f2d
wxHTTP::BuildRequest(wxString const&, wxString const&) 0x00000000004d5f70
wxHTTP::GetInputStream(wxString const&) 0x00000000004d77d5
wxURL::GetInputStream() 0x00000000004ca5d3
downloadAndExtractFile main.cpp:89
BackgoundThread::Entry main.cpp:303
wxThread::CallEntry() 0x0000000000749632
wxThreadInternal::PthreadStart(wxThread*) 0x000000000074a03f
start_thread 0x00007f4adf51aea7
clone 0x00007f4adf44adef
```

Comment: @B.A.Sylva, what is the backtrace at the time of the crash?

Comment: @B.A.Sylva, and I presume you worki with wx-3.2.2.1?

Comment: @Igor wxwidgets_gtk2_3.2.0

Comment: @Igor I have cross-compiled it 1 year ago on Debian 11 for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu. But I can do it again. I will try it now (it's 19:20 in Germany). Who knows maybe it solves something.

Comment: try with the latest 3.2.2.1.

Comment: @igor I cross-compiled v3.2.2.1, but i get the same SIGSEGV.

Comment: `GetInputStream()` is deprecated, so I would not pursue that part of the problem. `wxFileSystem` is recommended. However, I have had nothing but grief using wxWidgets HTTP classes with threads. I switched to using `restclient-cpp` for my wxWidgets applications.